# How to use an interface for REST API definition in Quarkus?

Tags: kotlin, jax-rs, quarkus, microprofile

I want to define a REST API using JAX RS against an interface, and then implement this interface in both the server and any number of clients. Quarkus doesn't seem to support this unless you duplicate parts of the API definition in the implementations.

Eg, it should be possible to do the following:

```
@Path("/hello")
interface GreetingApi {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    fun greeting(@PathParam("name") name: String): String?
}

class GreetingEndpoint(private val service: NameService) : GreetingApi {
    override fun greeting(name: String): String? {
        return service.greeting(name)
    }
}

@RegisterRestClient
interface GreetingClient : GreetingApi
```

However, both the client and server require an additional `@Path("/hello")` annotation in order for registration (without them under test it throws 404), which is both redundant and unnecessary duplication.

Is it possible to define the full API solely on the interface?

Comment: @Path supposed to go on the concrete class not the interface. This is stated in the specification.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha which spec and where? would you mind providing a reference? It seems to allow annotations on the members within the interface, why the difference?

Comment: Im only referring to the class level. It is in the JAX-RS spec.

Comment: This should work. I have a sample with it here: https://github.com/radcortez/microprofile-samples/blob/master/services/book-api/src/main/java/com/microprofile/samples/services/book/resource/BookApi.java. Is you interface in another module or library? If that is the case, you need to register, because Quarkus does not scan these by default: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#bean_discovery

Comment: @jimmy_terra jax-rs spec 2.0 states in 3.1 Resource Classes: "A resource class is a Java class that uses JAX-RS annotations to implement a corresponding Web resource.
Resource classes are POJOs that have at least one method annotated with `@Path` or a request method designator." Using quarkus 2, overriding the interface `@Path` at class level in the implementation works to be discovered. Read 3.6 as well

Answer (score 3):

[Jax-rs 2.0](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html) defines jax-rs resources (3.1) as having at least 1 jax-rs annotation. When overriding a superclass/interface annotation, then all annotations are overriden (eg if 3 annotations are present in the interface, overriding 1 of them will discard the other 2). The specification recommends overriding all annotations for consistency with other EE specifications (in 3.6).

The following should work:

```
@Path("/hello")
interface GreetingApi {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    fun greeting(@PathParam("name") name: String): String?
}

@Path("/hello")
class GreetingEndpoint(private val service: NameService) : GreetingApi {
    override fun greeting(name: String): String? {
        return service.greeting(name)
    }
}

@RegisterRestClient
interface GreetingClient : GreetingApi
```